# How can I do a POST call to my api with JSONHTTPClient?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, jsonhttpclient

I'm using JSONHTTPClient library from github in my Objective c application. I have a lot of calls to my api and all works, but when I try add a POST function with headers and body, I get an error:

> Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=2 "Bad network response.
>   Probably the JSON URL is unreachable."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Bad network response. Probably the
>   JSON URL is unreachable.}

I use the JSONFromURLWithString url to do a POST call. The api call works correctly, returning the data from server (I'm tested this from postman) But from this function in my objective c application I'm getting always error, why not get the response?

Am I sendind any data in bad format?

This is my code:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"var1", @"keyVar1", @"5" , @"keyvar2",  nil];//Here initialize my headers values into a dictionary

NSDictionary *dicty = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"6234", @"id", @"4324" , @"id2", nil];//This is my body
NSData *jsonDatass = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dicty options:0 error:nil];//Here convert my body to nsdata

[JSONHTTPClient JSONFromURLWithString:@"myURL" method:@"POST" params:nil orBodyData:jsonData headers:parameters completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err){

        NSLog(@"have error?: %@", err);
        NSLog(@"have response?: %@", json);

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for pass json in url first you need to convert json in to the string and then pass then string as a argument. Thats why in postman it works well.
I want to know the complete URL after you joining together，in the

```
  [JSONHTTPClient JSONFromURLWithString:@"myURL" method:@"POST" params:nil 
 orBodyData:jsonData headers:parameters completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err){
  }
```

method，your complete URL shoud be same as

`******************************** divider ***********************************`

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonDatass encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
myString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *uploadUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<YOU host URL>"?data=%@",myString];
```

also `parameters` Should be converted to string to splice into the url.